# How to monitor a spring boot app in a container docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a prometheus which is up on a container on docker windows using docker desktop .
I have a spring boot app which is on a container on docker in windows also .
I won't to monitor the spring boot app .
this is my file prometheus.yml :

[image]

but when running the prometheus container i'm getting an endpoint target like this even if my spring boot container is up :

[image]

Please note that in my spring boot app i'm using actuator , and without dockerizing it i could monitor it .

please help!

Comment: If you can reach both of these from your Windows host, then in Prometheus you need to change the address of your application from `localhost` to `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: I have changed it to host.docker.internal and now i'm getting this error : "INVALID" is not a valid start token